# How to make my object from combobox appear in listview

Tags: c#

[image]

**From the picture above you can see my program. The problem i have is that my combobox for Countries on the bottom does show up on my listview. I dont know why, has it to do with that Countries is not a string? and whats the solution. I have been trying for a very long time with this, i need all help there is for you guys to help. Thanks in advance**

Form 1 = listview

Form 2 = my customer manager (the picture above)

down here is inside Form1

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
{
CustomerFiles.Contact contact = new CustomerFiles.Contact();
    CustomerFiles.Address address = new CustomerFiles.Address();
    CustomerFrame customerframe = new CustomerFrame();

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if button OK is clicked then value will be inserted
        {
            // var item = string.Format("[{0}]",contact.ToString());

            listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("[{0}]", customerframe.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

Down here is inside Form2

```
public partial class CustomerFrame : Form
{

    CustomerFiles.Address address = new CustomerFiles.Address();
    CustomerFiles.Contact contact = new CustomerFiles.Contact();
    CustomerFiles.Countries country = new CustomerFiles.Countries();

    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    internal CustomerFiles.Phone phone { get; set; }
    internal CustomerFiles.Email email { get; set; }
    internal CustomerFiles.Address addressinfo { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    internal CustomerFiles.Countries countryinfo { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }

public CustomerFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<CustomerFiles.Countries> countries = new List<CustomerFiles.Countries> {
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 1, Name = "Bulgaria"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 2, Name = "France"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 3, Name = "Brazil"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 4, Name = "Russia"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 5, Name = "South Africa"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 6, Name = "Kurdistan"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 7, Name = "China"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 8, Name = "Japan"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 9, Name = "United States of America"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 10, Name = "UK"},
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 11, Name = "Australia"},    
      new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 12, Name = "Germany"},
     new CustomerFiles.Countries{ CountryId = 13, Name = "Sweden"},};

        cbCountry.DataSource = countries;
        cbCountry.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbCountry.ValueMember = "CountryId";
        cbCountry.SelectedValue = 1;

        btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;


        contact.ToString();
        address.ToString();

    }

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // inside contact 
        contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
        firstName = contact.FirstName;

        contact.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
        lastName = contact.LastName;

        contact.PhoneData = new CustomerFiles.Phone(tbCellPhone.Text);
        phone = contact.PhoneData;

        contact.PhoneData = new CustomerFiles.Phone(tbHomePhone.Text);
        email = contact.EmailData;

        //inside address class
        address.City = tbCity.Text;
        city = address.City;

        address.Country = new CustomerFiles.Countries(cbCountry.Text);
        countryinfo = address.Country;

        address.Street = tbStreet.Text;
        street = address.Street;

        address.ZipCode = tbZipCode.Text;
        zipcode = address.ZipCode;

    }



public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", contact.ToString(), address.ToString());
    }
```

And down here is inside my address class

```
    class Address
{
    private string city;
    public Countries country;
    private string street;
    private string strErrMessage;
    private string zipCode;


    public Address()
    {
        string strErrMessage = string.Empty;
        string street = string.Empty;
        string zipCode = string.Empty;
        string city = string.Empty;
    }

    public Address(string street, string zipCode, string city)
    {
        Street = street;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
        City = city;
    }
    public Address(string street, string zipCode, string city, Countries country)
    {
        Street = street;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
        City = city;
        Country = country;
        strErrMessage = string.Empty;

    }
 public Countries Country
    {
        get
        {
            return country;
        }
        set
        {
            country = value;
        }
    }
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]", city, zipCode, street, country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding the Text property from the form:

```
listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("[{0}]", customerframe.ToString()));
```

Change that to use the value you want to use.  It's not very clear what you want to display in the `ListView`.

Maybe it's as simple as:

```
listView1.Items.Add(cbCountry.SelectedItem);
```

Check for null, etc.

Make sure your `Country` class overrides the `ToString()` function like you have in your other classes.